# Why does the mathtools package define operators only \AtBeginDocument?

Tags: mathtools

What is the rationale behind defining operators like `\coloneq` in `mathtools.sty` using `\AtBeginDocument`?

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  ...
  \providecommand*\coloneq{\vcentcolon\mathrel{\mkern-1.2mu}\mathrel{-}}
  ...
}
```

What would break if these commands were defined at the end of `mathtools.sty`? What are the benefits of this detour?

I just noticed that in the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\defeq\coloneqq
\begin{document}
$a\defeq b$
\end{document}
```

`\defeq` stays undefined because of this and that one has to use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\defeq\coloneqq}
```

instead.

Comment: Well, at the end of the package is not being safe that another package loaded after `mathtools` will install its own version of `\coloneq` then. Putting it in `\AtBeginDocument` is 'safer', unless other packages loaded after `mathtools` hooks again into `\AtBeginDocument`, of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with any use of `\AtBeginDocument`, it delays execution until after the preamble. The benefit is that one can assess interactions with other packages that were loaded (before *or* after).

Using `\providecommand` ensures that if any other package (for whatever reason) creates some macro called `\coloneq`, it won't redefine it. However, if it doesn't exist, it will define it.

As a package writer, you don't know what other packages will be loaded with yours, and therefore you attempt to accommodate this with delayed definitions (using `\AtBeginDocument`), using `\def`s (to overwrite regardless of existence) or conditioning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The only difference between `\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand}` and `\providecommand` seems to be that the commands can be defined elsewhere using `\newcommand`. However, the packages `pxfonts` and `txfonts` define these commands in a way that also works if the commands already exist. So the effort of `mathtools` isn't really necessary.